# Forming a Test Data List using JAVA for selenium functional testing

Tags: java, arrays, list, selenium-webdriver, hashmap

I am trying to form a test data to verify the text of each using selenium. But having a problem in how we can validate the content using selenium. Can you please suggest how to achieve this and how the test data can be formed. MY test data actually looks like below:

```
    {
  "Items": [
      {
        "Title": "Plan",
        "Type": "secondary",
               "LinkList": [
          {
            "LinkTarget": "https://www.yahoo.com",
            "LinkText": "Find a Bar"
          }
        ],
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "Title": "Where We Go",
        "Type": "secondary",
               "LinkList": [
          {
            "LinkTarget": "https://www.google.com",
            "LinkText": "All Restaurants"
          }],
        "active": false
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normaly we have to check the following criteria

1.system response when **Valid  test data** is submitted

2.system response when **InValid  test data** is submitted

3.system response when **no data** is submitted

4.system response when test data is in an **invalid format or illegal format**

5.Test the data for **boundary value conditions**

6.Test Data in-sync with your **use cases**.

For all these you have to write selenium codes and execute to test the results. Better Using Framework like TestNG and JUnit

Comment: Thanks Anju, can you please suggest which methods can be used to form this data and how to iterate each data